# How to prepare a template - ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, html, repeater, eval

How can I like the following into the repeater.

as an example:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>

                <div id="haber-item"><%#Eval("metin")%></div>

<div id="haber-item"><a href="<%#Eval("pdf") %>" target="_blank"><%#Eval("metin")%></a></div>

                </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: How do I make the above example.

I can only as a link. "pdf" data come back empty How can I remove a tag.

Comment: what do you need  excatly ? I cant understant.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="haber-item">
    <a href='<%# Eval("pdf") %>' target="_blank" runat="server" visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("pdf").ToString()) %>'>
        <%# Eval("metin") %></a>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("pdf").ToString()) %>' Text='<%# Eval("metin") %>' />
</div>
```

P.S. that's wrong habit to assign the same id to more that one element on a page (I mean the `haber-item` div)

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: private void haberEN()
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT metin, pdf FROM tblHaberEn", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Repeater2.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
        
    }

Comment: <a id="A1" href='<%# Eval("pdf") %>' target="_blank" runat="server" visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("pdf")) %>'>

Comment: use `ToString()` instead of casting Eval method result to string

Comment: I've update answer. Just copy it and past onto your page. I hope you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
               <ItemTemplate>

                <div id="haber-item">
                  <%#Eval("metin")%>
                 </div>

                <div id="haber-item">
                 <a href='<%#Eval("pdf") %>' target="_blank"><%#Eval("metin")%></a>
               </div>

              </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: How do I make the above example.

I can only as a link. "pdf" data come back empty How can I remove a tag.

Comment: pdf = null
<%#Eval("metin")%>

pdf = is not null
<a href='<%#Eval("pdf") %>' target="_blank"><%#Eval("metin")%></a>

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good i. How can I without a tag is empty, the value of a pdf.

Comment: I get it , Youll have to do it in the ItemDataBound event in the c#.